# Why are two cursors running and moving in an embedded applicaton at the same time?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, beagleboard

I am using qt-embedded 4.7.1. I was able to cross-compile the framework on the host machine to target the [Beagleboard](http://www.beagleboard.org) machine, but when I deployed and ran a demo application on this target, **I saw two cursors running at the same time**, one for the target operating system and another for the executing qt application.

In other words, I can communicate with the qt app only with its own cursor, and without the original cursor -before running that application?
I use QWS for the qt-application, since I use this command "target$./demoapp -qws" to run the demo app on the target.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for this problem ..

The problem was that: when I ran the Qt application with -qws option, that would run it using a different windowing system ( other than the default windowing system Gnome (for example))

The solution was installing the Qt IDE (QtCreator) on the beagle board and running the Qt application from this IDE - not using the shell - , this step will launch the application using the same windowing system used by the operating system ..

hope this helps :)

Comment: Is there any other way? other than installing the Qt IDE